# Как сделать замену данных по условию в SQL?

Tags: android, sql

**Например,** у меня есть таблица со столбиком "цвет". Как мне изменить поля со значение "красный" на "белый".(В android)

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой запрос к БД Вам нужен:

```
"UPDATE table_name SET field_name = newFieldValue WHERE field_name = oldFieldValue"
```

Чуть приблизив к конкретно Вашему вопросу:

```
"UPDATE table_name SET цвет = белый WHERE цвет = красный"
```